# Hosting a Workflow in an MVVM application

Tags: mvvm, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm designing a MVVM application that does not use WPF or Silverlight.  It will simply present web pages in HTML5, styled with CSS3.

The domain is a perfect case for using WF because it involves a number of activities in a long-running process.  Specifically, I am tracking the progress of interactions with a customer over a 30 day period and that involves filling out various forms at points along the way, getting approvals from a supervisor at certain times, and making certain that the designated order of activities is followed and is executed correctly.

Each activity will normally be represented by a form on a view designed to capture the desired information at that step.  Stated differently, the view that a user sees will be determined by where she is in the workflow at that moment.

My research so far has turned up examples where the workflow is used to execute business logic in accordance with the flowchart that defines it.

In my situation, I need for a user to login then pick up where she left off in the workflow (for example, some new external event has occurred and she needs to fill out the form for that or move forward in the workflow to that step.)

And I need to support the case where the supervisor logs in and can basically be presented with activities that need approval at that time.

So... it seems to me that a WF solution might be appropriate, but maybe the way I want to use it is inverted - like the cart pulling the horse so to speak.

I'd appreciate any insight that anyone here can offer.

Thanks - Steve

Comment: FYI, AFAICT you can't host the designer in a silverlight app, but you can in an xbap.

Comment: Thanks @Will.  I won't be using either, just the MVVM pattern.  But my real issue is how to drive the view presented to the user based on the state of the workflow.  This seems like a reasonable thing to want to do, but I haven't found any references to this anywhere.  Hoping someone on this site can lend some direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have designed an app similar to yours, actually based on WPF, but the screens shown by the application are actually driven by workflows.
I use a task-based approach. I have some custom activities that create user tasks on a DB. There are different type of tasks, one for every different form type that the application supports. When the workflow reaches one of these special activities, the task is saved to DB and the WF goes idle (bookmark).
Once the user submits the form, the wf is resumed up to the point where another user task is reached and so on.
Tasks can be assigned to different users along the way (final user, supervisor, ..) and they have a pending tasks list where they can resume previous wf instances, etc.

Then, to generate user views (HTML5 forms in your case) you have to read the pending task and translate that into the corresponding form.

Hope you find it useful